# Get another local users home directory

Tags: windows, windows-8, powershell, local

I am trying to automate the copying of profile data from one user account to another. This other user account is being created in a PowerShell script from an Administrator account. I am copying over template

This script is to be run on a Windows 8 machine. I thought I might be able to assume the USERPROFILE would be [HomeDrive]\Users[AccountName]\ but I hit a case where it is actually [HomeDrive]\Users[AccountName].[MachineName].

I am using the following snippet to create the users account,

```
function CreateLocalUser([string] $userName, [string] $password, [string] $description)
{
    $computer = "localhost"

    $objOu = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
    $objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $userName)

    $objUser.SetPassword($password)
    $objUser.SetInfo()

    $objUser.Description = $description
    $objUser.SetInfo()

    return $objUser
}
```

How can I get the created users home directory without using Powershell extensions?

Answer (score 2):

I would look up the reg key for the user's profile folder you want to copy to eliminate ambiguity.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\[Users SID]\Profile Image Path
```

As for creating the home directory, that's the tricky part. if this is a completely new user, you can *try* Microsoft's USMT tool, specifically the [loadstate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766226(v=ws.10).aspx) exe, and create the account that way. I haven't used it this way but my first attempt would be to create a profile on some computer, then back it up with scanstate. Next, you can deploy it to any machine with loadstate, specifying the new account name as a parameter.

What loadstate does is automatically create the user's profile (including the profile folder, that you want to copy the files to), and it restores files that were backed up (which is minimal if you backup an empty or fresh profile), but the important part is that you get a profile folder created.

USMT is available as a download from MS and comes with the Windows 8 ADK also.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run a command as the new user to initialize a profile folder. Wrote a function that returns the users profile folder path.

```
function New-UserProfileFolder ([string] $username, [string] $password) {

    $sec_password = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $sec_password

    # Run command to create profile folder
    Start-Process cmd /c -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -Credential $credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    # Get information from WMI
    $user = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/cimv2 -Class win32_useraccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='$username'"
    $userprofile = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/cimv2 -Class win32_userprofile -Filter "SID='$($user.sid)'"

    $userprofile.localpath
}
```